# Is there any way to control when authentication with Game Center happens?

Tags: ios, gamekit, game-center

The following code is called once upon `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`; however, it runs each time my app re-enters the foreground again.

```
[localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
    {
        // Some implementation
    }
}];
```

This makes sense, according to the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW11):

> ... it also retains your completion handler for later use. Each time your application is moved from the background to the foreground, Game Kit automatically authenticates the local player again on your behalf and calls your completion handler to provide updated information about the state of the authenticated player.

Is there any way to delay this authentication until Game Center is actually needed?  The reason I ask is that I would like to avoid showing the "Welcome back, userX!" banner each and every time the app is brought to the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, at least not with public APIs.